# How to obtain the first 4 rows for every 20 rows from a CSV file

Tags: python, pandas

I've Read the CVS file using pandas and have managed to print the 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th row for every 20 rows using `.iloc`.

```
Prem_results = pd.read_csv("../data sets analysis/prem/result.csv") 
Prem_results.iloc[:320:20,:]
Prem_results.iloc[1:320:20,:]
Prem_results.iloc[2:320:20,:]
Prem_results.iloc[3:320:20,:]
```

Is there a way using `iloc` to print the 1st 4 rows of every 20 lines together rather then seperately like I do now? Apologies if this is worded badly fairly new to both python and using pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`groupby.head`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
Prem_results.groupby(np.arange(len(Prem_results)) // 20).head(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concat slices together like this:

```
pd.concat([df[i::20] for i in range(4)]).sort_index()
```

MCVE:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':np.arange(1000)})
pd.concat([df[i::20] for i in range(4)]).sort_index().head(20)
```

Output:

```
    col1
0      0
1      1
2      2
3      3
20    20
21    21
22    22
23    23
40    40
41    41
42    42
43    43
60    60
61    61
62    62
63    63
80    80
81    81
82    82
83    83
```

Start at 0 get every 20 rows
Start at 1 get every 20 rows
Start at 2 get every 20 rows
And, start at 3 get every 20 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this while reading the csv itself.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for chunk in pd.read_csv(file_name, chunksize = 20):
    df = pd.concat((df, chunk.head(4)))
```

More resources:
You can read more about the usage of `chunksize` in Pandas official documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

I also have a post about its usage [here](https://www.avichawla.com/pandas-load-big-csv-file-as-chunks/).